# Tensored Over Abelian Groups?

Tags: ct.category-theory, linear-algebra, homological-algebra

Suppose I have an category additive category C (i.e. the hom sets are enriched in abelian groups and there are finite direct sums). Suppose further that C has cokernels. Then I can make C tensored over finitely presentable Abelian groups by the following ad hoc construction:

First define $\mathbb{Z}^n \otimes X := \oplus_n X$. Now given a finitely presentable abelian group A, choose a presentation, i.e. realize $A$ as the cokernel of $f:\mathbb{Z}^r \to \mathbb{Z}^g$. Define $A \otimes X$ as the cokernel of the induced map:

$\mathbb{Z}^r \otimes X \to \mathbb{Z}^g \otimes X$

My questions: Is there a way to do the same thing which feels more canonical and less ad hoc? Under what conditions will C be tensored over all abelian groups?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Given an object $X$ in an additive category $C$ and an abelian group $A$, define the object $A\otimes X$ in $C$ by the rule $Hom_C(A\otimes X,\:Y) = Hom_{Ab}(A,Hom_C(X,Y))$, where $Ab$ denotes the category of abelian groups.  If arbitrary direct sums and cokernels (arbitrary colimits, in other words) exist in an additive category $C$, the tensor product $A\otimes X$ exists in $C$ for any abelian group $A$ and any $X\in C$.  It can be constructed just as you describe in your question, except that finite direct sums should be replaced with infinite direct sums.

Comment: I thought of this as I was writing the question, but wanted to see what other people would say, anyway. When you say "infinite direct sum" you mean coproduct, right? When I hear "direct sum" I usually think something which is simultaneously a product and a coproduct. Even for the category of abelian groups infinite direct sums in that sense don't exists.

Comment: "Direct sum" and "coproduct" (in an additive category) are the same thing for me.  I thought it was the standard terminology.  As to the product and the coproduct of an infinite number of copies of a certain object, these two never coincide in an abelian category, unless the object is zero.

Comment: There's already a term for something which is simultaneously a product and a coproduct: biproduct.  

Comment: In certain contexts "biproduct" can have a different meaning (e.g. in the context of bicategories). But arguing over terminology is a little  ridiculous. The main point is that this is a beautiful answer. 

Comment: I like this definition for the tensor product!  It's uniquely determined by Yoneda's Lemma, correct?  (I just want to check that I'm not missing something important.)

Comment: @Manny: The object is unique, because it represents the functor $Y\mapsto\hom_{\mathrm{Ab}}(A,\hom_C(X,Y))$.

Answer (score 7):

This question feels a little meta-mathematical; I'm not sure whether you mean a construction that is less ad-hoc, or some description of the properties of said object that makes it clear that it's not an ad-hoc object.  Leonid gave a description in the latter terms above.

One construction is that you can take as an index category I the category of finitely generated free abelian groups F equipped with a basis and a map F → A, with morphisms being commuting triangles that ignore the basis.  Then A⊗X is the colimit of F⊗X as F ranges over I.  (You need choices of basis in order to define a functor, and this assumes that you actually have a direct sum *functor*.)

A related description is that if C is your category, D is the category of finitely generated abelian groups, and E is the category of finitely generated free abelian groups with a basis (and maps ignoring the basis), then I'd like to say that you have a diagram of functors

C×D ← C×E → C

given on the left by forgetting and on the right by tensoring, and your desired "tensor product" functor is a left Kan extension C×D → C.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a general context for the same answer.  Let V be a bicomplete symmetric monoidal closed category such that the underlying-set functor $\hom_V(I,-)$ is conservative, where I is the unit object, and which is "extremally well-copowered" in the sense that the isomorphism classes of extremal epimorphisms out of any object form a set.  If C is a V-enriched category whose underlying ordinary category is cocomplete, then C is tensored over V.  This is Prop. 3.46 in Kelly's book "Basic concepts of enriched category theory", http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/10/tr10abs.html

In particular, V = abelian groups satisfies these conditions, as does V = R-modules.  The "extremally well-copowered" condition is quite mild, but conservativity of the underlying-set functor is quite strong and fails in many other cases.

Comment: Is "extremely well-copowered" implied by "locally presentable"?

Comment: What is "conservative"?

Comment: "Conservative" means "reflects isomorphisms", i.e., if $U = \mathrm{hom}_V(I, -)$ sends $f$ to an isomorphism, then $f$ was already an isomorphism. A non-example is the category of sheaves of abelian groups on something with the objectwise tensor product, where $U$ sends a sheaf to the underlying set of its global sections.

Comment: Yes, locally presentable implies well-copowered wrt all epimorphisms, hence a fortiori also wrt extremal epimorphisms; this is 1.58 of Adamek-Rosicky.

Comment: Topological spaces are another good non-example, where U sends a space to its underlying set.  A continuous bijection need not be a homeomorphism.  Chain complexes are another non-example, where U sends a chain complex to the set of 0-cycles.


Comment: Wow. Okay. Conservative is a really strong condition. Can this be weakened? 

Comment: If you read Kelly's book, you'll see that assuming extremal well-copoweredness, a small set of objects of V is strongly generating iff V is its closure under ordinary colimits.  And if C is a V-category whose underlying ordinary category is cocomplete, the class of V-objects for which C admits tensors is closed under ordinary colimits.  Hence one generalzation is that if C admits tensors with the objects in some strongly generating set, it must admit all tensors.  The previous result is the special case for the single object I, which is a strong generator iff V(I,-) is conservative.

Answer (score 1):

Incidentally, this is part of a more general story about algebraic theories and relates to [Tall-Wraith monoids](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Tall-Wraith+monoid) (surprise, surprise).

Take an algebraic theory, say $V$, (which we identify with its category of models in Set) and a category $D$ with "sufficient structure".  Then we can consider co-$V$-objects in $D$.  These represent covariant functors $D \to V$.  Let $H$ be such.  Now if we take a co-$V$-object in $V$, say $B$, then by composition we get a covariant functor $D \to V \to V$.  Under the "sufficient structure" assumption on $D$, representability is equivalent to having a left adjoint.  As both $D \to V$ and $V \to V$ are representable, both have left adjoints.  Thus their composition has a left adjoint and so is representable.  Hence there is a co-$V$-algebra object representing $B_* H_*$ which we may as well write as $B \otimes H$.  Lots of obvious naturality then implies that there is a corresponding bifunctor $VV^c \times DV^c \to DV^c$.  In the particular case that $D = V$ we see that $VV^c$ is monoidal - which is the starting point of the construction of Tall-Wraith $V$-monoids - and more naturality then implies that the bifunctor $VV^c \times DV^c \to DV^c$ is an action of $VV^c$ on $DV^c$.

This generalises even further to give a - slightly odd-looking - action of $VV^c$ on the category of $V$-objects in $D$.

In the specific case in question, $V$ is the category of abelian groups and as $D$ is an abelian category, every object in $D$ is automatically a co-$V$-object in $D$.

(Bits of this story are in the Hunting of the Hopf Ring, other bits will be in a forthcoming paper with Sarah Whitehouse on Tall-Wraith monoids.)